# Mongo Map Reduce error

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

Being a newbie to MongoDB I'm trying to get a MapReduce call going.
Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
mongos> db.events.mapReduce(m,r,"errors");
Fri Apr 12 11:39:15.637 JavaScript execution failed: map reduce failed:{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "MR parallel processing failed: { errmsg: \"exception: reduce -> multiple not supported yet\", code: 10075, ok: 0.0 }"
} at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:L970
mongos>
```

I'm using Mongo 2.4.0

My events collection looks like this:

```
{ "sid" : "1UADM45MCGRTW ", "time" : ISODate("2013-04-08T11:33:13.229Z"), "class" : "S", "service" : "service1" }
{ "sid" : "1UADM45MCGRTW ", "time" : ISODate("2013-04-08T11:33:13.229Z"), "class" : "I", "service" : "service1" }
{ "sid" : "1UADM45MCGRTW ", "time" : ISODate("2013-04-08T11:33:13.236Z"), "class" : "E", "text" : "error message" }
{ "sid" : "1UADM45MCGRTW ", "time" : ISODate("2013-04-08T11:33:13.239Z"), "class" : "F", "service" : "service1" }

{ "sid" : "1UDO3H7YUOK08 ", "time" : ISODate("2013-04-08T11:33:08.095Z"), "class" : "S", "service" : "service2" }
{ "sid" : "1UDO3H7YUOK08 ", "time" : ISODate("2013-04-08T11:33:08.095Z"), "class" : "I", "service" : "service2" }
{ "sid" : "1UDO3H7YUOK08 ", "time" : ISODate("2013-04-08T11:33:08.173Z"), "class" : "E", "text" : "another error message" }
{ "sid" : "1UDO3H7YUOK08 ", "time" : ISODate("2013-04-08T11:33:08.188Z"), "class" : "F", "service" : "service2" }

{ "sid" : "1UDO3JVXIS2UZ ", "time" : ISODate("2013-04-08T11:28:39.480Z"), "class" : "I", "service" : "service1" }
{ ""sid" : "1UDO3JVXIS2UZ ", "time" : ISODate("2013-04-08T11:28:39.480Z"), "class" : "S", "service" : "service1" }
{ "sid" : "1UDO3JVXIS2UZ ", "time" : ISODate("2013-04-08T11:28:40.853Z"), "class" : "F", "service" : "service1" }
{ "sid" : "1UDO3JVXIS2UZ ", "time" : ISODate("2013-04-08T11:28:40.852Z"), "class" : "I", "service" : "service1" }
```

My intention is to get all "E" entries and combine them with the "service" field of the corresponding "sid" of a "F" entry. So this should be very simple but I couldn't get it going (because of the above error).

The map/reduce functions I used are:

```
var m = function() {
    if (this.class == "E") {
        value = { time: this.time, error: this.text };
        emit(this.sid, value);
    } else if (this.class == "F") {
        value = { service: this.service };
        emit(this.sid, value);
    }
}


var r = function(key,values) {
    return values;
}

db.events.mapReduce(m,r,"errors");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you want to accumulate all the errors for each key and that means you have to emit an array of documents and then your reduce has to combine them into a single array (as it's going to receive an array of arrays).

The other problem you have is that you want to combine different classes of each unique cid into some combined reduced result, but your reduce function is not even trying to do that.

It's hard to know how many different class values you might get for each sid but if it's like the example data you gave, I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
var m = function() {
    array = [];
    if (this.class == "E") {
        value = { time: this.time, error: this.text };
        array.push(value);
        emit(this.sid, {a:array});
    } else if (this.class == "F") {
        value = { service: this.service };
        array.push(value);
        emit(this.sid, {a:array});
    }
}


var r = function(key,values) {
    result = {a:[]};
    values.forEach(function (v) {
       result.a = v.a.concat(result.a);
    });
    return result;
}

db.events.mapReduce(m,r,"errors");
```

On your example, the resultant collection will look like this:

```
> db.errors.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : "1UADM45MCGRTW ",
    "value" : {
        "a" : [
            {
                "service" : "service1"
            },
            {
                "time" : ISODate("2013-04-08T11:33:13.236Z"),
                "error" : "error message"
            }
        ]
    }
}
{
    "_id" : "1UDO3H7YUOK08 ",
    "value" : {
        "a" : [
            {
                "service" : "service2"
            },
            {
                "time" : ISODate("2013-04-08T11:33:08.173Z"),
                "error" : "another error message"
            }
        ]
    }
}
{
    "_id" : "1UDO3JVXIS2UZ ",
    "value" : {
        "a" : [
            {
                "service" : "service1"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

You can probably add a finalize function to transform this array into a result that's a single document but that depends on the format of the resultant collection that you want to have and on the expected input for each sid.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation ([troubleshoot reduce function](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/troubleshoot-reduce-function/))
"*The reduce function must return an object whose type must be identical to the type of the value emitted by the map function*"

As you are emitting an object, reduce should also emit an object as well - so wrap `values` in an object and you should be good to go.